# Is there any way to make SHFileOperation modal?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have an MDI based frame app that is calling SHFileOperation, something like this:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT opDelFiles = {0};
opDelFiles.hwnd = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd();
opDelFiles.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
opDelFiles.pFrom = (LPCTSTR)fileData;
opDelFiles.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO; 

SHFileOperation( &opDelFiles );
```

If SHFileOperation displays a dialog to the user (e.g. "Are you sure?") although the dialog remains on top of the frame the user can still interact with the frame, ie the shell dialog is passing Window messages to the frame. Is there anyway to prevent this and make the shell dialog behave like a modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply disabling the window until `SHFileOperation()` exits?

Comment: It's not that simple, that will likely cause the app to lose the foreground love.  PostMessage required.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by 'PostMessage required.' What would you post?

Comment: Your own custom message number.  The window procedure should handle it and disable the window.  This ensures the window is disabled *after* the dialog appears.

Comment: You have to be sure to re-enable your window *before* the SHFileOperation completes - otherwise you won't get focus back. And since there's no way to get notified *before* the SHFileOperation is going to get rid of it's window, you have no way of making it work correctly. Only SHFileOperation knows when it's going to hide it's window, only it would be qualified to disable and re-enable your window for you.

Comment: @IanBoyd "*there's no way to get notified before the SHFileOperation is going to get rid of it's window*" - a thread-local hook via `SetWindowsHookEx` or `SetWinEventHook` can detect the dialog being created and destroyed